# How can a trace be a vector? (I know this usually isn't true, but can it happen in numerical algebraic geometry?)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, numerical-methods

I am currently reading *Decomposing solution sets of
polynomial systems using derivatives* by Brake, Hauenstein, and Liddell ([link](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Ejhauenst/preprints/bhlTraces.pdf)) and it's not clear to my how the trace in Theorem 1 is a vector. Do others see how? When I try to go through the examples myself on page 3 of the pdf, I am having a hard time computing the trace.

I know a trace is the sum of the diagonals of a square matrix. But I am stumped on what this square matrix is. I also don't clearly see how I can solve for $\mathcal{V}(\ell-t\cdot v)$.

For the definition of Newton's [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace they are talking about is not the sum of the diagonal elements of a square matrix.

On page 2, at the bottom, they define $x_i(t)$ as paths in $X \subset \mathbb C^N$. The trace, which is defined in Theorem $1$ as $\sum_{i \in \mathcal I} x_i(t)$ therefore is a path in $\mathbb C^N$. This is what you are thinking of as a vector. More useful to think of it as a moving locus of points in this context IMO.

You might find the first couple of pages of *Trace Test* by Leykin, Rodriguez, and Sottile [here](http://amj.math.stonybrook.edu/pdf-Springer-final/018-0084.pdf) (with pictures!) helpful in understanding what's going on. They explain the trace and the intuitive meaning of Theorem 1 very clearly.